# Entire Harddrive to linux swap

Tags: memory, hard-disk, swap, ram

I have an old hard drive that is less than 50Gb and a computer that only has about 4Gb of ram (and ~250Gb main HDD). I was thinking about using the second drive as an entire drive linux-swap partition.

I have read through the U&L question: [Can I accelerate swap by using multiple harddrives?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43646/can-i-accelerate-swap-by-using-multiple-harddrives) which is from 2012. The comments suggest that an old drive would likely be slow and possibly failing, which is something to be cautious about.

I've also heard that memtest86+ used to be able to create a kernel memory map blacklist, which seems to be outlined here: [How to blacklist a correct bad RAM sector according to MemTest86+ error indication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75059/how-to-blacklist-a-correct-bad-ram-sector-according-to-memtest86-error-indicati) .

Is there a way to combine that these to take advantage of the very large but slow memory of a HDD even though it may be end-of-life (and thus at least prefail) hardware?

### tldr

How can I use memmap'ing in gnu/linux on a 2nd HDD that is entirely a linux-swap partition, even if it is potentially failing?

Comment: use it as /tmp instead

Comment: You can try to partition the HDD into two and regularly run `badblocks` on it by deactivating one swap partition and checking that for badblocks. That and `smartd`.